# How to make a unique layout for the main page?

Tags: sveltekit

I have multiple pages on my web-site and only main page should have a different layout? How can I achieve this?

```
src/
 - page1/ <- LayoutB
 - page2/ <- LayoutB
 - page3/ <- LayoutB
 - index.svelte <- LayoutA
```

If I use `__layout.svelte` in the `src/` folder it will apply for every page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update November 2022**

This approach was tested in

```
npm -v @sveltejs/kit
8.19.2
```

To make a unique layout for a specific page (or group of pages) you need to use [group](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts-group).

```
src/
  routes/
    (unauthenticated)/
      welcome/
      register/
      login/
      +page.svelte
      +layout.svelte (this layout applies to welcome/, register/ and login/
    (authenicated)/
      home/
      settings/
      +page.svelte
      +layout.svelte (this layout applies to home/, settings/ and dashboard/
+page.svelte
+layout.svelte (this layout applies to all pages in unauthenticated/ and authenticated/)
```

---

I was able to find a solution by using <s>[named layouts](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/layouts#named-layouts)</s> from SvelteKit

The solution to my problem will look like this

```
src/
 - page1/ <- LayoutB
 - page2/ <- LayoutB
 - page3/ <- LayoutB
 - __layout.svelte (LayoutB)
 - __layout-main.svelte (LayoutA)
 - index@main.svelte <- LayoutA
```

I created a layout file with `-main` suffix and used this name as a reference to the layout in my `index@main.svelte` file

Comment: Can this be done with the latest version of SvelteKit?

Comment: @Tracy don't know :(. I know that they replaced the `__layout` with `+layout`.

Comment: @Tracy Nope, you need to use layout groups which result in a massive duplication of folder structure across those groups.

Comment: @Tracy I updated solution to the current latest version of SvelteKit (8.19.2)

Comment: The shell code you're using to output the SvelteKit version (`npm -v @sveltejs/kit`) does **not** do what you think it will do - it will output the version of **npm** used, not SvelteKit ("8.19.2" corresponds to an npm version, while SvelteKit as of the time of writing is still at major version 1). To output the version of SvelteKit, consider using `npm ls @sveltejs/kit` instead.